# How to create a Gantt chart in Google Sheets or Excel where there are multiple dates for one task?

Tags: excel

[image]

How can I create Gantt chart with multiple start/stop dates for one task? In the picture above you can see that one task starts on Jan 4 - Jan 25 and then again on Feb 1 - Feb 15.
I have the usual Task/Start Date/End Date and Duration columns but when I try to add Start Date 2, End Date 2 and Duration 2 to the chart, it doesn't align correctly and goes off the chart area.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Identify those tasks differently as either:

1. it finished on Jan 25 in which case the one that started on Feb 1 is another task or
2. it is just one  task from Jan 1 to mar 22.

So Task 1a, Task 1b, Task 1c etc